# How to display Video in full screen width

Tags: android, shell, android-layout, listview

**How to display Video in full screen width.**

```
   <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                   <VideoView
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="200dp"
                       android:id="@+id/video_view"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"

                       />

               </LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the attached image**:

[image]

Comment: android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" comes in RelativeLayout ! not in LinearLayout

Comment: it will be helpful if you could upload all the layout xml file

Comment: Thank issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout

```
   <RelativeLayout
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                   <VideoView
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="200dp"
                       android:id="@+id/video_view"
                       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"

                       />

               </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add screen orientation Landscape in Android mainifist file and put

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and make parent as a **RelativeLayout**